# Send input to iphone app with ssh and open

Tags: ios, iphone, ssh

I want to open an iPhone app (sonetel - which is an app to make phonecalls via voip) and send a number to the app in order to have the app dial this number. Currently I'm using

```
open com.sonetel.Sonetel
```

to open the app, but it doesn't seem like open is able to handle options or input in general. Is there a way to tinker with an app on the iPhone via SSH?

If it's just a sonetel app problem, I can also use the standard iPhoneCall app.

I'm using iOs 8.1 on an iPhone5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, you want to pass an argument to your app.

App bundles aren't designed to be passed command line arguments, so its impossible.

But there are other techniques to pass some data to executable.

1. Xcode has a section `Arguments Passed on Launch` where you can
   specify some values, and from the code within the app you have to
   use

   `NSArray * arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];`

   in order to handle the arguments. You can find more info on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeRun.html)
2. The other option is probably to use `NSUserDefaults`. For this you
   have to read following [article](http://perspx.com/archives/parsing-command-line-arguments-nsuserdefaults/).

Comment: Ok, thought this to. How hard would it be to code a iPhone app that just makes a phone call and does some input? I'm a php/Python/javascript developer willing to learn some objective c...